# Azure Static Web App with custom authentication(Azure AD) has a login Loop

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-static-web-app, azure-app-registration

I'm trying to build custom authentication for a Azure Static Web App. I've followed the tutorial of [assigning roles via Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/assign-roles-microsoft-graph). I've it working for two users, everyone else get's a login loop.

Added custom authentication in the staticwebapp.config.

```
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html",
    "exclude": ["/images/*.{png,jpg,gif}", "/css/*"]
  },
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/logout",
      "redirect": "/.auth/logout"
    },
    {
      "route": "/.auth/login/twitter",
      "statusCode": 404
    },
    {
      "route": "/.auth/login/github",
      "statusCode": 404
    },
    {
      "route": "/profile-management",
      "allowedRoles": ["manager"]
    },
    {
      "route": "/*",
      "allowedRoles": ["authenticated", "consultant", "manager"]
    }
  ],
  "auth": {
    "rolesSource": "/api/auth/getroles",
    "identityProviders": {
      "azureActiveDirectory": {
        "userDetailsClaim": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
        "registration": {
          "openIdIssuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}",
          "clientIdSettingName": "Aad_Client_Id",
          "clientSecretSettingName": "Aad_Client_Secret"
        },
        "login": {
          "loginParameters": ["resource=https://graph.microsoft.com"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "responseOverrides": {
    "401": {
      "redirect": "/.auth/login/aad",
      "statusCode": 302
    }
  }
}
```

The client id from the app registration is set in the application settings of the Azure Static Web App and the secret is set in the application settings as a Key Vault Reference. The Azure Static Web App is added to the Azure Key Vault via managed identity.

[Azure Static Web App - Application Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pfL3.png)

[Azure Static Web App - App Registrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5twQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've deleted the User.Read permission in the app registration. The two users logged before the deletion, that's why they had access. Other users couldn't consent because the permission wasn't there. Fixed the issue by adding the User.Read permission in the app registration, so that user can consent the permission.